# How to remote desktop to a Windows Vista machine from a Redhat machine?

Tags: windows-vista, remote-desktop, remote-control, redhat-enterprise-linux, remote-access

I can find [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/turn-on-remote-desktop-in-windows-vista/) about remote desktop in Vista, but none that tells me how to remotely control my Vista machine from my Redhat machine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use tsclient (Terminal Server Client) which comes installed under **Applications -> Internet -> Terminal Server Client**. It looks very similar to Remote Desktop on Windows.

Set the protocol as RDPv5 and away you go!

[image]

See the Red Hat article on [Connecting Using Terminal Server Client](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Desktop_Deployment_Guide/s1-ddg-remote-desktop-tsclient.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/US/home.aspx) which is free and works from a web browser. Or there is [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) if you want something easy I would suggest LogMeIn, works around routers what not.

Answer (score 1):

xrdp has both a client and a server version. Install xrdp client, and then use it to connect to the Windows Vista terminal server.